# Не работает приложение в сборке Release

Tags: visual-studio, ассемблер, сборка, masm32

Есть проект в Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.9.1. Проект типа Console Application C++. Все настройки проекта, файлы проекта, код, прикладываю скринами, дабы было нагляднее.
Суть проблемы такова, что программа не просто работает, а работает правильно при запуске через Debug версию. Сборка Release вылетает ориентировочно в моменте, когда идет вызов ASM функции, хотя отладчик VS показывает точку ошибки на моменте печати массива, который был обработан ASM функцией. Скрины тоже прилагаю.
В чем может быть дело? Методом тыка были проведены некоторые тесты и в одном из них VS сослался на ошибку доступа к памяти в коде ASM, именно доступа.
В общем, я новичок, особенно в ASM и его таких специфических сборках, представления не имею как справляться с этой проблемой, т.к. мне кажется дело тут не в алгоритме (ошибке) в функции ASM, т.к. Масм32 такое собирает и работает оно без проблем.
Может есть у кого какие хотя-бы догадки, помогите пожалуйста?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;
extern  "C"  void AsmFUNC(int *, int *, int, int);

void printMatrix(int *mass, int n, int m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(4) << mass[i*m + j];
        }
        cout << endl;
        }
    }


int main()
{
    short n, m;
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    do {
        cin.clear();
        system("cls");
        cout << "Введите количество строк(<100)> "; cin >> n;
    } while ((n >= 100)||(n<1));
    do {
        cin.clear();
        system("cls");
        cout << "Введите количество столбцов(<100)> "; cin >> m;
    } while ((m >= 100) || (m < 1));
    int *mass = new int[n*m];
    int *sum = new int[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) sum[i]=0;
    cout << "Ввод элементов массива:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << "Элемент[" << i + 1 << "]"<<"["<<j+1<<"]=";
            cin >> mass[i*m+j];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Массив до обработки" << endl;
    printMatrix(mass, n, m);
    AsmFUNC(mass, sum, n, m);
    cout << "Массив после обработки" << endl;
    printMatrix(mass, n, m);
    cout << "Массив сумм" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) cout << " " << sum[i];
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

ASM

```
.586
.model flat, C
.data
lenstr dd 0
i dd 0
j dd 0
summa dd 0
temp dd 0
temp2 dd 0
.data?
.code


AsmFUNC    PROC mass:dword,sum:dword,n:dword,m:dword
mov edi,mass
mov eax,m
shl eax,2
mov lenstr,eax     
mov ecx,m
m1:
push ecx
push sum
mov ecx,n
xor esi,esi
xor eax,eax
m2:
add eax,[edi+esi] 
add esi,lenstr
loop m2
pop sum
mov ebx,sum
mov [ebx],eax
add ebx,4
mov sum,ebx
add edi,4
inc i
pop ecx
loop m1
mov eax,4
cdq
mov ebx,m
mul ebx
mov ecx,sum
sub ecx,eax
mov ebx,ecx
mov ecx,m
mov i,0
c1:
mov eax,i
push ecx
mov ecx,m
sub ecx,i
mov j,eax
c2:
mov edi,mass
mov eax,i
mov edx,[ebx+eax*4]
mov temp,edx
mov eax,j
mov edx,[ebx+eax*4]
cmp temp,edx
jg c3
jmp c3_1
c3:
mov temp2,edx
mov edx,temp
mov [ebx+eax*4],edx
mov edx,temp2
mov eax,i
mov [ebx+eax*4],edx
push ecx
mov ecx,n
c4:
mov eax,j
mov edx,[edi+eax*4]
mov eax,i
mov esi,[edi+eax*4]
mov [edi+eax*4],edx
mov eax,j
mov [edi+eax*4],esi
add edi,lenstr
loop c4
pop ecx
c3_1:
inc j
loop c2
inc i
pop ecx
dec ecx
jnz c1
 ret
AsmFUNC    ENDP
end
```

[image: Файлы проекта]

[image: Настройки проекта 1]

[image: Настройки проекта 2]

[image: Настройки проекта 3]
[image: Отладка]

Настройки командной строки Microsoft Macro Assembler:

```
ml.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"Release\assembly.obj" /Fl"" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Ta
```

ПРОБЛЕМА, В МОЕМ СЛУЧАЕ, РЕШЕНА добавлением след. кода перед заполнением значениями массива:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            mass[i*m + j] = 0;
        }
    }
```

Правда я не понимаю почему так, т.к. в ЛЮБОМ случае у меня в коде идет ввод значения с клавиатуры и занесение их в массив, т.к. все элементы проинициализируются и что толку заполнять перед этим их нулями, практически то же самое делается, но с клавиатуры. Если кто понимает, прошу, объясните мне пожалуйста. Спасибо

Comment: Мое предположение: в релизном варианте mass хранится не в стековой переменной, а в регистре (esi или edi например), а ваша процедура внутри это значение перезатирает. По соглашению stdcall процедура может модифицировать eax, edx, ecx, остальные регистры нужно восстанавливать перед выходом.

Comment: Второе предположение - ассемблерная часть компилируется по соглашению stdcall, сишная часть вызывает ассемблерную по соглашению cdecl, в итоге съезжает стек при выходе из процедуры. В этом случае, правда, не работало бы и в отладочном варианте.

Comment: @insolor если первый вариант Вашего предположения, то почему ситуация исправляется при инициализации нулями? При том, что опять же, напомню, после инициализации нулями сразу же идет идентичный цикл, с единственным отличием, что идет ввод значений из клавиатуры.

Comment: @insolor По поводу второго, видимо раз Вы так написали и я новичок, то видимо такое возможно, но в коде явно указано использование соглашения C (cdecl).
Проверил. По адресу edi находится начало массива mass. Только я теперь еще более запутан, т.к. код АСМ я не изменял, а лишь добавил инициализацию нулями перед заполнением значениями из клавиатуры, как это спало от затирания edi?

Comment: @insolor видимо потому что дубликат адреса хранится в формальных параметрах функции и по счастливой случайности, т.к. при проектировании даже в голову не приходило, что при выходе из функции в регистре должен лежать адрес массива, в алгоритме адрес дублируется в edi. Спасибо за наводку. Где-то вообще можно более подробно прочесть на эту тему, чтобы потом не браться за голову или исключительно непредсказуемое решение компилятора и проверять что куда "спрятано" вручную?

Comment: На каких входных данных вы наблюдаете ошибку? Почему этой информации нет в вопросе? Попробовал позапускать - нет никаких падений. Как вы предлагаете нам воспроизводить проблему?

Comment: @AnT падения при любых наборах данных. Не могу конечно сказать точно, что 100% любых, так как бесконечное количество проверить не могу, но закономерности не наблюдаю, поэтому нечего описывать в вопросе. Просто запускаю исполнимый файл, заполняю элементы цифровыми значениями и (если верить отладчику) при попытке вывести массив после обработки АСМ функцией получаю ошибку.
Если все же вам нужно конкретно, то сейчас проверил и могу Вам сказать, что при вводе кол-ва строк = 1, кол-во столб. = 1 и значение элемента = 1 вылетает отпечатав только "Массив до обработки" и сам массив.

Comment: Почему помогает инициализация нулями - возможно из-за нее отключается какая-то оптимизация, и компилятор начинает хранить адрес массива в переменной а не в регистре. Нужно сравнивать в скомпилированном виде, чтобы сказать точно.

Comment: @insolor я пробовал без инициализации нулями добавить в конце АСМ функции `mov edi,mass`, то есть восстановить адрес в регистр - и это не помогло(

Comment: Попробуйте сделать вначале `push edi` `push esi` `push ebx` (3 строками), в конце (перед `ret`) `pop ebx` `pop esi` `pop edi`.

Comment: @insolor это сработало, инициализация теперь не имеет значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По соглашениям stdcall, cdecl в процедурах могут свободно использоваться регистры eax, ecx, edx, значения остальных регистров должны восстанавливаться перед выходом из процедуры. В процедуре `AsmFUNC` используются регистры `esi`, `edi`, `ebx`. Скорее всего со включенной оптимизацией компилятор размещает какие-то из переменных (в том числе указатель на начало массива) в регистрах, а не в стеке, после выполнения ассемблерной процедуры эти переменные затираются. Принудительная инициализация массива `mass` скорее всего заставляет компилятор поместить эту переменную в стек. *"Скорее всего" - потому что нужно смотреть под дизассемблером, какой код фактически компилятор генерирует в каждом случае.*

Проблема решается сохранением значений используемых регистров в начале процедуры и восстановлением перед выходом из нее:

```
AsmFUNC    PROC mass:dword,sum:dword,n:dword,m:dword
push edi
push esi
push ebx

; остальной код

pop ebx
pop esi
pop edi
ret
AsmFUNC    ENDP
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша программа падает в первую очередь потому, что в оптимизированном коде перед вызовом `AsmFUNC` компилятор загружает значения `mass` в регистр `ebx` и далее действует в рамках предположения, что значение этого регистра не разрушается вашей функцией. Вы же в своей функции разрушаете значение `ebx`.

Для эксперимента я убрал ручной ввод и задал все константами, про каковой причине мой код может отличаться от вашего, но суть от этого не меняется

```
    AsmFUNC(mass, sum, n, m);
0026469A  mov         ebp,dword ptr [esp+2Ch]  
0026469E  push        0Bh  
002646A0  push        4  
002646A2  push        ebp  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
002646A3  push        ebx    // `ebx` - это `mass`
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
002646A4  call        AsmFUNC (0264760h)  
    cout << "After" << endl;
002646A9  push        offset string "After" (0283310h)  
002646AE  push        offset std::cout (0294338h)  
002646B3  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (02610E0h)  
002646B8  push        eax  
002646B9  call        std::endl<char,std::char_traits<char> > (02613B0h)  
    printMatrix(mass, n, m);
002646BE  push        0Bh  
002646C0  push        4  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
002646C2  push        ebx    // снова используется `ebx` без восстановления из памяти
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
002646C3  call        printMatrix (02643C0h)
```

Comment: что тогда находится в `edi`? Я пробовал убрать весь свой АСМ код и загрузить по адресу edi свое произвольное тестовое число, после выполнения программы оно оказывалось на первом элементе массива, что соответствует моему понимаю, значит в `edi` находится адрес массива. Если же я загружаю, например, какое-то свое значение в `ebx` или, например, `esi`, то программа падает.